# Redirect output to /dev/null when two commands are piped?

Tags: android, linux, bash

I am trying to build a docker image for android CI systems but wanted to avoid a heavy log file. So to avoid output on stdout I wanted it to redirect to `/dev/null`. I am a novice in using linux commands.

My actual command is:

```
echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
```

And also I am commenting multiple lines togeather with `&&`. So It results in something like this:

```
echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-27" && \
echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "platform-tools"
```

But, the command (`$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"`) displays a large license file on screen and it results in a large log file, which ultimately exceeds the log file limit where I am trying to run.

To avoid this, I wanted pass the output to `/dev/null`. So, I tried it with:

```
echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-27" && \
echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "platform-tools" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

It results in licences not being accepted which it should.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried this?

`echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-27" > /dev/null 2>&1 \ 
&& echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "platform-tools"`

I belive you should dev null the specific command line.

Comment: @FábioCorreia That didn't worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest:

```
{ command1 | command2 && command3 | command4; } >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: This did worked! Awesome! What that last semicolon did was awesome

Comment: What was the problem? The redirection to `/dev/null` was actually only being applied to the command after the `&&`, wasn't it?

Comment: @Cyrus The command ran successfully. I just wanted to verify with the generated build that it accepted the code or not. Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 I also tried putting it in each separate lines. But that didn't worked.